# UWP: Is there a way to be notified when the app reaches a certain usage of memory?

Tags: events, memory-management, uwp, out-of-memory

I am developing a UWP app which could have a fair amount of memory pressure.

I want to adapt the memory usage, so that I don't get short of it when I need.

Is there a way inside the App (I am thinking mainly about an event that I can register from my App or MainPage, or something similar...) to get notified when i.e. the memory usage of the App reached 90% of the allowed value for my App (e.g. in tablets) or 90% of the available memory of the overall system?

Thank you!

Comment: hi am facing same situation, did you find a solution for this !? kindly help.

Comment: It seems a bug of the platform, apparently not yet solved

Comment: when I try to use MemoryManager_AppMemoryUsageIncreased event, it is alwasys triggering for the app launch , in fact it should not.  It should only get triggered while "AppMemoryUsageIncreased" . I am not sure how to check this.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for this is the MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsageIncreased event:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.memorymanager.appmemoryusageincreased

If this isn't granular enough for your purpose, you could monitor MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsage property yourself, relative to the MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsageLimit property

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.memorymanager.appmemoryusage 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.memorymanager.appmemoryusagelimit

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, unfortunately I am retrieving very weird values from the properties of MemoryManager (e.g. AppMemoryUsageLimit = 19563606016, but after 2 GB an OutOfMemoryException is raised; AppMemoryUsage = 340320256, but in the TaskManager I see 80MB...; ExpectedAppMemoryUsageLimit = 18446744073709551615, which is obviously bogus...). Moreover, the event MemoryManager_AppMemoryUsageIncreased is not fired, even if I encountered an OutOfMemory Exception. How is this possible?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Can you log it via FeedbackHub?

Comment: Open FeedbackHub from the start menu and select "Report a problem". Enter the problem details and select category Developer Platform/API Feedback.

Comment: Seems like the problem still exist. MemoryManager_AppMemoryUsageIncreased still gets not fired, even when running into an OutOfMemoryException...Can someone confirm that?